# please tell me correct way to use usb_modeswitch in ubuntu saucy

Tags: wireless, networking, usb

I have one mobile router "hw0-2e".
(https://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/product/data/hw02e/index.html )(japanese only)

I want to use this by usb connection as my pc is desktop and no wifi.
I know this one can connect with windows pc by usb connection.
but if I connect it with Ubuntu, my pc cannot identify it as usb modem,my pc identifies it as CD.

So I think ,if I install usb_modeswitch to ubuntu, I will use it.
then,I installed it to Ubuntu saucy,
and I searched `vendorID=12d1 ,productID=1506`
and read 
http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?t=708
and tried a lot of things.
but I cannot use "hw0-2e" as router.

please tell me correct way to use usb_modeswitch in Ubuntu saucy.